# Enabling scroll with xlValidateList

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to be able to scroll a list that I create with a dropdown using VBA. My current code is:

```
With DASHBOARD.Range("AC17").Validation
 .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop,Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="='Hidden Template'!$AH$3:$AH$72"
 .IgnoreBlank = True
End With
```

It creates the dropdown list just fine, but I would like ability to scroll the list with my mouse wheel when selecting from it.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The scrolling in this area apparently doesn't work very well.  A user on another site, Jaafar Tribak, has posted a way to do this: [scroll Data Validation List](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/411578-mousewheel-scroll-long-cell-validation-dopdown-lists.html).

It's kinda involved, but the code appears to be pretty plug-and-play.  See the last post on the page.

Additionally, if you put your mouse on the actual scroll bar and start scrolling, it does start working kind of.  You might be able to come up with some sort of solution using controls